# How to use Scikit Learn Wrapper around Keras Bi-directional LSTM Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, lstm

I have created a Keras LSTM model that does sequence classification.
I have 27 sequences in the Training set and 18 sequences in the Test set. Each sequence has 4000 time-steps that I have achieved by padding with zeroes. Each sequence is a combination of 2499 parallel series. This means I have 2499 Features.

- Dimensions of X_Train is (27 x 4000 x 2499)
  :27-Sequences, 4000 Timesteps in each sequence and 2499 features.
- Dimension of Y_Train is (27 x 4000 x 1)
- Dimension of X_Test is (18 x 4000 x 2499)
- Dimension of Y_Test is (18 x 4000 x 1)

I am using Bi-directional LSTM Model with return_sequences set to True

My ultimate goal is to get Feature Importances using ELI5 Package's Permutation Importance.

Since ELI5 package does not support Keras framework, I want to use a Scikit learn Wrapper around keras to get it to behave like scikit learn.

Then I can finally use ELI5 package on my model to get Important features.

I have used these parameters:

- layer1_units = 40
- layer1_act = 'tanh'
- go_backwards = False
- return_sequences = True
- merge_mode = 'concat'
- lr = 0.01
- epochs = 2
- batch_size = 200

I am going to use this lstm model in the build_fn attribute of KerasClassifier().

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn= lstm_Trial.model(),  epochs=3, batch_size=40, verbose=1)
```

Then I am trying to use .fit() method.

```
model.fit(x = X_Train, y = Y_Train_Ori)
```

This throws an error.

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 model.fit(x = X_Train, y = Y_Train_Ori)
>    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py in fit(self, x, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
>       203             y = np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
>       204         else:
>   --> 205             raise ValueError('Invalid shape for y: ' + str(y.shape))
>       206         self.n_classes_ = len(self.classes_)
>       207         if sample_weight is not None:
>
> ValueError: Invalid shape for y: (27, 4000, 1)

How do I use KerasClassifier properly so that Ultimately I am able to use ELI5 package?

Comment: Can you please reduce your problem to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There seems to be a lot of unnecessary information which makes it hard to debug. Try to replicate the problem in the simplest way possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem and to avoid double-posting, I would like to share with you [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861879/5305519) which I have posted on another Stackoverflow question similar to yours.

> TL;DR: eli5 requires 2d arrays but LSTM layers need 3d arrays, so you cannot get it to work currently